# Generalize a program using iglob

Tags: python, glob

I have a program which scans a folder or path for a given type of files and then analyze them.

```
import glob  
path = raw_input("ENTER PATH TO SEARCH: ")  
list_of_file = glob.iglob('*.txt')  
for filename in list_of_file:    
      print filename`
```

But in this script the program will scan the directory only in which it was stored in `path` statement gets no value.

Now if I write:

```
list_of_file = glob.iglob(path + '*.txt')
```

this also do not make my work going.

So please suggest a way in which whatever path I enter the program follows that path and search for particular file types, no matter where I kept my script.

Answer (score 0):

I assume English is not your first language, so please forgive me if I have misunderstood your question. It seems to me that you want to be able to enter a directory and then find all the ".txt" files in that directory?

If so, then the following code should suffice to give you an example:

```
"""Find all .py files is a given directory."""
import os
import glob

path = raw_input("Enter path: ")
fullglob = os.path.join(path, "*.py")
for fn in glob.iglob(fullglob):
    print os.path.split(fn)[1]
```

The last line takes off the path you put in to ensure iglob() finds the right directory. You can use the help() function to get documentation on os.path.join() and os.path.split().